# How to add search icon to my button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How to add a Glyphicon search icon to my search button. This is the bootstrap code for the button.

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

How can i add glyphicon glyphicon-search in replace of the Submit text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the Submit text with the following span:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
```

More details on glyphicon codes can be found [here](https://www.glyphicons.com).

I personally use font-awesome as I like their constant updates to their icon base.

Answer (score 1):

Just append a `span` element with the glyphicons class to the button.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  Search
</button>
```